# How should I prove that $ |e^{ia}-e^{ib}|=2\sin\frac{|a-b|}{2}\leq|a-b| $?

Tags: calculus

How is it possible to prove that:
$$
|e^{ia}-e^{ib}|=2\sin\frac{|a-b|}{2}\leq|a-b|?
$$

Specifically, I'm looking for an analytic technique to show that the equality $|e^{ia}-e^{ib}|=2\sin\frac{|a-b|}{2}$ is correct.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Doesn't this follow from $\sin(x)\leq x$ replacing $x$ with $\frac{x}{2}$?

Comment: notice that sin(x) =(e^(ix) - e^(-ix))/2i

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio♦ Thank you for your reply! Could you please explain, why we can assume that $\sqrt{\sin^2\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)}=\left|\sin\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)\right| = \sin\left(\frac{|a-b|}{2}\right)$ for all $a,b$, not just for those $\{a,b: |a-b|<2\pi\}$?

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio♦ Thank you again for your awesome reply! Do you mind adding it as an answer so I may accept it? I believe that it's more beautiful and concise than a geometric argument.

Comment: @Konstantin: all right, I am removing my previous comments since they are not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\|e^{ia}-e^{ib}\|^2=(e^{ia}-e^{ib})(e^{-ia}-e^{-ib}) = 2-2\cos(a-b) = 4\sin^2\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)$$

Due to the fact that $\sin$ is a Lipschitz-continuous, odd function with a derivative bounded by $1$, by assuming that $|a-b|$ does not exceed $2\pi$ we have:
$$ \|e^{ia}-e^{ib}\|=2\sin\left(\frac{|a-b|}{2}\right) \leq |a-b|.$$

Answer (score 1):

Draw a unit circle in the complex plane, and the points $e^{ia}$ and $e^{ib}$. The inequality $|e^{ia}-e^{ib}|\leq |a-b|$ is true because the first term is the distance between $e^{ia}$ and $e^{ib}$ along a straight line, while $|a-b|$ is the distance between the same two points along the arc of the unit circle, possibly plus some multiple of $2\pi$.

The equality $|e^{ia}-e^{ib}|=2\sin\frac{|a-b|}2$ you get if you draw the four line segments

- From the origin to $e^{ai}$
- From the origin to $e^{bi}$
- From $e^{ai}$ to $e^{bi}$
- From the origin to the middle of the previous line

Now $|e^{ia}-e^{ib}|$ is the length of the third segment, while $\frac{|a-b|}2$ is the angle of one of the two right angled triangles you have just drawn.

Answer (score 1):

A useful trick when you have expressions such as $e^{ia}-e^{ib}$ is to collect $e^{ib}$, so
$$
e^{ia}-e^{ib}=e^{ib}(e^{i(a-b)}-1)
$$
Now set $a-b=2c$:
$$
e^{i(a-b)}-1=e^{ic}(e^{ic}-e^{-ic})=2ie^{ic}\sin c
$$
Thus
$$
|e^{ia}-e^{ib}|=|e^{ib}|\,|e^{ic}|\,|2ie^{ic}\sin c|=2\lvert\sin c\rvert=
2\sin\lvert c\rvert=2\sin\frac{|a-b|}{2}
$$
Next recall that $-x\le \sin x\le x$, for every real $x$.

Comment: Very nice technique! Thank you for the reply!

Comment: @Konstantin With complex numbers you have trigonometry essentially already plugged in. `;-)`